# TypeScript: How to import a class from a submodule?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a TypeScript app using both `.ts` and `.d.ts` files. References are made using the triple slash notation `/// <reference path=...>`. My app has the following definition file:

```
declare module APP {

    class Bootstrap {
        constructor();
    }

}
```

I then declare a module named `"app"` so I can import it in other files:

```
declare module "app" {
    export = APP;
}
```

Assuming my `Bootstrap` class exists, I then import the `Bootstrap` class using:

```
import { Bootstrap } from 'app';
```

**This works.**

Now I create a submodule on `APP`, like so:

```
declare module APP.Service {
    class Async {
        constructor();
    }
}
```

I make another declaration for the submodule:

```
declare module "app/service" {
    export = APP.Service;
}
```

Now, when I import the class `Async` like so:

```
import { Async } from 'app/service';
```

I get the following error message:

```
Module '"app/service"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.``
```

**How do I be import a class from a submodule?**

*NOTE*

I have found a workaround by declaring a global `var`:

```
declare var APP_SERVICE: APP.Service.IService; // IService exists
```

And exporting that on my module:

```
declare module "app/service" {
    export = APP_SERVICE;
}
```

The downside of this is that my global namespace get's polluted with `var`'s I don't use, because I will use `Service` through `App.Service`, not `APP_SERVICE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about creating a nice, reusable, maintainable declaration file for a module, the preferred way is by using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings), as it handles aspects such as type dependency management and submodules very well for you.

1. Create a separate repository for the typings your are writing.
2. Add `typings.json` file with the name and path to your main typings. eg:

   ```
   {
     "name": "my-main-module",
     "main": "index.d.ts"
   }
   ```
3. Add your the type declarations for your main module to `index.d.ts` and the type declarations for submodules to `submodule-name.d.ts`.

   **submodule.d.ts**

   ```
   export interface submoduleInterface {
     someProp: number
   }
   ```

   **index.d.ts**

   ```
   import * as submodule from './submodule'

   export interface mainInterface {
     someProp: number
   }
   ```
4. Run `typings bundle index.d.ts -o bundle.d.ts`. This will bundle all your typings into one type declaration file, declaring the proper submodules and respecting all the necessary dependencies between modules, submodules and even external modules.
5. Either copy this file to a `custom-typings` directory in your original project, or submit this repo to the [typings registry](https://github.com/typings/registry) so other people can also profit from it , and pull it in with a normal `typings i my-module-name`.

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/pellejacobs/04e99fe7688065d408524b3ee067dd72) with all the code, and the resulting `bundle.d.ts`. Here is a [repo](https://github.com/pellejacobs/typed-redux-persist) that uses both submodules (`redux-persist/constants`) as external dependencies (`redux`), and that got ultimately submitted to the typings registry.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'll have another go at my typings structure. Though I'm not planning on making my project and typings public, it's good to know how I would go about it. Sometime in the future I'll probably create a public API so I'll be needing this. thanks :)

Comment: while this works, i dont see any  easy way to generate this structure when creating a typescript project. No one wants to create their own d.ts files when tsc can output them. How do we make tsc output something that can be imported easily from consumer libraries.